# Is it possible to save data to a json file on local disk using $resource.save without using any server side implementation?

Tags: json, angularjs

I am trying to build an Employement Management App in **AngularJS** where a basic operation is adding an employee.
I am displaying details using a service and getting Json data from the mock json file i am using.
Similarly, can i add form data to a textfile on the harddisk.
I have seen it done in a tutorial using $resource.save.
If at all it is possible without any server side code please share the example,it would be helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: do you have a link to that tutorial ? have tried out the html5 File APIs ? http://updates.html5rocks.com/2011/08/Saving-generated-files-on-the-client-side

Comment: what are goals? To be able to work offline? or simply not to have any server side? Numerous other cloud storage solutions ( some are free) as well that only need javascript to connect to api's

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of HTML5 local browser storage, as this does not require folder access. Mode datails here http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html

AngularJS has modules for local storage which you can use to access such storages like this https://github.com/grevory/angular-local-storage